# Spring JPA query for a dynamic table name

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am putting same entity of type X in multiple tables whose names match the pattern "dynamic_string_SOME_STATIC_TEXT". I would derive the table name from entity X like this: X.code + _SOME_STATIC_TEXT

What I want to achieve something like this:

```
public default List<X> findAll(String code) {
    return findAll_internal(code + "_SOME_STATIC_TEXT");
}
    
@Query("select * from ?1")
public List<X> findAll_internal(String code);
```

But I did not find the correct syntax (if that is possible at all)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do custom query in JPARepository in such case. Only "genuine" jdbc parameters can be given this way.

You need to implement the `findAll_internal` method by your self and forge your query (with Criteria for instance).